# Excel Count Macro

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have an excel 2016 spreadsheet with about 1000 rows of data. Each row has a name like xxx_type1, or xxx_type2, or xxx_type3, etc. They also have further subdivisions, another column has a number (1,2,3,4, etc.) I would like to keep track of how many rows of each type the spreadsheet has and also how many are within each subdivision.

For example if the spreadsheet contains 100 rows of type1, I would like it to show on a separate sheet that I have 100 rows of type1 and 20 are in subdivision 1, 30 are in subdivision 2, 50 are in subdivision 3.

Does anybody have a macro that could do this or know a way I could make this happen?

I am thinking a pivot table might be the way to go, any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: Very unclear question. Please consider rewriting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you had your names in column A and subdivisions in column B, then the formula

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"*_type2")
```

would determine how many "type2" records you had.

And the formula

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"*_type1",$B:$B,2)
```

would determine how many "type1" records were in subdivision "2".

---

Below is an example layout / formulas that would summarise it for you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Thank you for your help and sorry for any confusion with my question.

Comment: (@Pbreezy - You can mark this as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post, under the up/down arrows.)

Comment: @BruceWayne - I love your capitalisation of "The Answer" :D